# How to modify the Python source code in order to add a new AST node?

Tags: python, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree, asdl

For example, if I was to create a node called "Something" that I wanted to use in a Python AST tree, where and which changes would I have to add to Python source code in order to do that?

I know that I should start out with Python.asdl where the AST grammar is defined. Then I should move onto ast.c.

Unfortunately, I am unsure where exactly I have to make the changes in the ast.c file in order to implement the node.

Also, for simplicity, lets say that I just want the node as a placeholder, meaning that it should not do anything except be able to insert itself into a tree.

Answer (score 2):

No need to dive into `Python.asdl` yet!  Then you have to go chasing around for an ASDL parser and then you have to figure out what to do with it (although this is a worthy exercise in itself).  You can stay within Python thanks to the amazing `ast` module.

Be sure to check out Eli Bendersky's [article on the matter](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/11/28/python-internals-working-with-python-asts/).

Here is an example he provides where an AST is constructed and `eval`'d from scratch!

```
import ast

node = ast.Expression(ast.BinOp(
                ast.Str('xy'),
                ast.Mult(),
                ast.Num(3)))

fixed = ast.fix_missing_locations(node)

codeobj = compile(fixed, '<string>', 'eval')
print eval(codeobj)
```

#### `ast.NodeTransformer`

Check out the `ast.NodeTransformer` class if you want to transform an existing AST.

Here is an example from the above blog postwhich modifies string values to be 
prepended with `str:`.

```
class MyTransformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Str(self, node):
        return ast.Str('str: ' + node.s)
```

Comment: I am familiar with Eli Bendersky's article on this; however, it deals with a different area than what I'm talking about.

I am hoping to actually add a new TYPE of node into it. So, for example, there is ast.Str(s), and I want to make it so there is ast.Undefined().